# Cargar traductor de js y json en paginas externas

Tags: javascript, html5, json

tengo una web a la cual le cree una funcion para traducir con js y json la cuestion es que al entrar a paginas externas estas no se traducen, intente exportando e importando datos pero no funciono, Alguien que me ayude???

Este es el div que tengo para que se tradusca

```
          <div id="flags" class="flags">
              <div class="flags_item" data-language="es">
                 <img src="../multimedia/img/españa.png" alt="España" class="bandera">
                  </div>
              <div class="flags_item" data-language="en">
                 <img src="../multimedia/img/British.png" alt="British" class="bandera">
                </div>
```

Codigo js

```
const flagsElements = document.getElementById("flags");
let textsChange = document.querySelectorAll("[data-section]")

flagsElements.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
   changeLanguage(e.target.parentElement.dataset.language);
});

const changeLanguage = async (language) => {
  const loadJson = await fetch(`../language/${language}.json`);
  const texts = await loadJson.json();

for (const textChange of textsChange) {
    const section = textChange.dataset.section;
    const value = textChange.dataset.value;

    textChange.innerHTML = texts[section][value];
   }
};
```

El funcionamiento es algo simple, al leer el id del elemento carga el data-lenguaje, busca y traduce segun los datos del json, pero como dije solo funciona con 1 pagina a la ves.

Hay alguna forma de que al traducir la pagina principal y que al entrar a otra se tradusca segun el idioma de la principal????

Comment: Supongo que usando localStorage puedes hacerlo, es decir, coges y guardas el valor del idioma en localStorage cada vez que se ejecute la función changeLanguage, y durante la carga de las páginas lees el valor del idioma guardado y lo aplicas.

Comment: Como se haria eso?, , me puedes ayudar soy un poco nuevo en js

Comment: Pude solamente guardar el dato del lenguaje y leerlo en otra pagina pero luego no supe como traducirlo :c

Comment: Si has conseguido leerlo en otra página entonces vas bien. Ahora tan solo debes ejecutar la función **changeLanguage()** pasándole ese valor en la nueva página para que aparezca traducida en el idioma guardado.

Comment: De que forma hago eso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
const flagsElements = document.getElementById("flags");
let textsChange = document.querySelectorAll("[data-section]")

flagsElements.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  changeLanguage(e.target.parentElement.dataset.language)
});


const changeLanguage = async (language) => {
  localStorage.setItem('language', language);
  const loadJson = await fetch(`../language/${language}.json`);
  const texts = await loadJson.json();

  for (const textChange of textsChange) {
    const section = textChange.dataset.section;
    const value = textChange.dataset.value;

    textChange.innerHTML = texts[section][value];
  }
};

if(language = localStorage.getItem('language')) {
  changeLanguage(language)
}
```

donde lo que hacemos es usar [localStorage.setItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) para guardar el dato **language** cada vez que se hace clic sobre cualquier idioma, y en las siguientes cargas del documento (o de cualquier otro documento que comparta este script) reconocerá el idioma guardado gracias al [localStorage.getItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) y si lo halla entonces aplicará el cambio de idioma de la página.

Comment: Te lo agradesco mucho,  me funciono perfectamente, lo necesitaba para un proyecto evaluado :)